# JAWS Accessibility issue : aria-label attribute for option tag is not working

Tags: html, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

```
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option aria-label="volvo" role="option">Vo</option>
    <option aria-label="mercedes" role="option">me</option>
    <option aria-label="opel">Op</option>
    <option aria-label="audi">Au</option>
  </select>
```

I've some issue with the above code while running in IE11.

```
<option aria-label="volvo" role="option">vo</option>
```

Google Chrome is reading the select box options from aria-label attribute properly as "volvo", but in IE11 it is reading only "vo"

Comment: remove the `role="option"` and give it another try. If that fails add `role="listbox"` to the `<select>` and put the `role="option"` back. Failing that we will have to use visually hidden text, which I can help you with but I would expect the first suggestion to work.

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried these options, none of them worked for me.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use the full words. I only ask as from an accessibility perspective it isn't just screen reader users you need to think about, it is also people with cognitive impairments who may not be able to make the association between "vo" and "volvo" (for example). If you have a valid use case that is fine but though I would check as to make this work we would have to use a lot of `aria` and create our own `<select>` (listbox) and that may make overall accessibility worse due to support. This is because we can't use visually hidden text in a standard `<select>`

Comment: Thanks, I've a valid reason which I'm not able to expose, I tried several options all of those didn't work for me.